# Laravel select like %value% wildcard query

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Does anybody know why the LIKE part is not working in Laravel 4?

```
$a = DB::select('select *, 
                        day(WN_DATE) WN_DAYOFMONTH,
                        month(WN_DATE) WN_MONTH,
                        year(WN_DATE) WN_YEAR
                 from mytable
                 where year(WN_DATE)
                 like %?%
                 order by WN_DATE DESC',
                array($_SESSION['filterOn']));
```

When using `like ?` , the this is working but when I add the `%`, as in `like %?%` then it does not work anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are misplacing the % % operators, notice the difference below - they should not be put aside the `?` placeholder, rather inside:

```
$query = "select *, day(WN_DATE) WN_DAYOFMONTH, month(WN_DATE) WN_MONTH, year(WN_DATE) WN_YEAR from mytable where year(WN_DATE) like ? order by WN_DATE DESC";

$param = '%'.$_SESSION['filterOn'].'%';

$result = DB::select($query , array($param));
```

Comment: That soled my problem. Thx